# Memory issue: Constructing lower triangular matrix in batches (in a vectorised way)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tensorflow, vectorization

Following is what I am trying to achieve:

Given an array that looks like:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Please keep in mind that this is small array of shape [9 by 9] and can be initialized in one go. The array that I want to construct is of shape [90000 by 90000] hence can not be initialised in one go.

After converting this [9 by 9] array into batches, it looks like:

```
    [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]],

    [[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]],

    [[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
    [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
    [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

I can use these individual slices to perform operations.

How can I initial an array of [90000 by 90000] in batches, maintaining the placement of ones in the array?

I have tried [tf.linalg.LinearOperatorLowerTrinangular()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/LinearOperatorLowerTriangular) operator. This is what the output looks like:

```
>>> arr = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorLowerTriangular(tf.ones((3,3,9)))
>>> arr.to_dense()
<tf.Tensor: id=28, shape=(3, 3, 9), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

In the output, you can see that the ones in each batch start from the first index.

Also, when I initialize "arr":

```
>>> arr = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorLowerTriangular(tf.ones((3,3,9)))
```

I have used `tf.ones()`, in my case I can not even use this to initialize 90000 by 90000 array.

Please suggest any efficient way to construct/initialise such a matrix?

Edit:

What exactly I am looking for? a logic as to how can I make chunks/sub matrices of the a big matrix 90000 by 90000. For example, I can create 10 sub matrices of size 9000 by 90000. However, how can I initialize these 10 sub matrices to look like a single lower triangular matrix.
I have will be using these sub-matrices to perform vector-matrix multiplication. Once I can find a way to assign values to these sub matrices (in a way that when appended together looks like a single lower triangular matrix of ones) then after performing vector-matrix multiplication, I can append all the 10 resultant matrices into one.

Comment: I am not quite sure exactly what you want. You want to build pieces of a big triangular matrix, like in a loop? Can you give some idea of how you would use this?

Comment: @jdehesa I have edited the question, please take a look. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if this is what you need, but here is a way to compute something like that by chunks in a loop in TensorFlow (here 2.x, but should be analogous for 1.x):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def mult_tril_chunks(vector, num_chunks=None, chunk_size=None):
    # Function accepts either number of chunks or size of each chunk
    # Last chunk may have different size
    if num_chunks is None == chunk_size is None:
        raise ValueError('one and only one of num_chunks and chunk_size must be given.')
    vector = tf.convert_to_tensor(vector)
    # Compute number of chunks or chunk size depending on given parameters
    s = tf.shape(vector)[0]
    if chunk_size is not None:
        chunk_size = tf.dtypes.cast(chunk_size, s.dtype)
        num_chunks = (s // chunk_size) + tf.dtypes.cast(s % chunk_size != 0, s.dtype)
    else:
        n = tf.dtypes.cast(num_chunks, s.dtype)
        chunk_size = s // n + tf.dtypes.cast(s % n != 0, s.dtype)
    # If you know all chunks will always have the same size
    # you can instead pass element_shape=[chunk_size]
    ta = tf.TensorArray(vector.dtype, size=num_chunks, element_shape=[None],
                        infer_shape=False)
    # Do computation in a loop
    _, ta = tf.while_loop(
        lambda i, ta: i < num_chunks,
        lambda i, ta: _mult_tril_chunks_loop(i, ta, vector, s, chunk_size),
        [0, ta]
    )
    # Return concatenated result
    return ta.concat()

def _mult_tril_chunks_loop(i, ta, vector, s, chunk_size):
    # Chunk bounds
    start = i * chunk_size
    end = tf.math.minimum(start + chunk_size, s)
    # Make slice of lower triangular matrix
    r = tf.range(s)
    tril_slice = r <= tf.expand_dims(tf.range(start, end), axis=1)
    tril_slice = tf.dtypes.cast(tril_slice, vector.dtype)
    # Compute product
    mult_slice = tf.linalg.matvec(tril_slice, vector)
    return i + 1, ta.write(i, mult_slice)

# Test
vector = tf.range(10)
# Result with normal computation
tril = tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((10, 10), vector.dtype), -1, 0)
res = tf.linalg.matvec(tril, vector)
print(res.numpy())
# [ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45]
# Giving number of chunks
res2 = mult_tril_chunks(vector, num_chunks=3)
print(res2.numpy())
# [ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45]
# Giving chunk size
res3 = mult_tril_chunks(vector, chunk_size=4)
print(res3.numpy())
# [ 0  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45]
```

Since you are concerned about memory usage, it may be worth checking out some of the more advanced parameters to [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop), such us the number of parallel iterations to run.